# Bootstrap horizontal form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I trying to create a horizontal form in bootstrap and have used the code they've given in the documentation. In the example they have given the input boxes fill the entire column space. For some reason this does not happen for me even if I copy the code. How to I get mine to be the same format?

Here is how it looks on the bootstap website
[image]

Here is an image of how this looks in my code
[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2>Account Details</h2>
      <form action="/account" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="height" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Height</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" value="{{ account_details[0].height }}" id="height" name="height" min=0 max=300 step=1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its working as expected, did you link correctly the bootstrap css file?

Comment: @dippas I have changed the link to an image, hope this helps you understand what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because of `max='300'`; when you set `max` condition for an input, size of that input change to max width that it needs to fill input for max value and because of that width change to a smaller input:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2>Account Details</h2>
        <form action="/account" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="height" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Height</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input class="form-control" type="number" id="heightname="height" min=0 step=1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The result with this should be like :
[image: this]

Comment: Thanks I also don't understand why the labels and input boxes have a wide gap between them? and why do the input boxes fill the rest of the width as it does in the boostrap example?

Comment: You want to your labels and inputs be in a line. Is it true?

Comment: yes I would like it to look like the bootstrap example

Comment: did you add correctly the reference of `bootstrap`? I will update my answer and I'll put the correct reference in my html header. check it and give me some response again.

Comment: It's fixed no I had something interacting with it in a css file, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, found bootstrap was interacting with something in my css page